# Google Maps JavaScript API and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a map project, that enable users to find nearby specific places (say, a swimming pool club in your neighborhood).

I'm required by the client to build the map such that, the map displays the various swimming pools (map markers) in a users location on the map. Close quartered locations are to be grouped in a cluster.

I'm also required by the client to build the map such that, when a user clicks on a map marker representing a particular location (swimming pool club), a modal window opens up which plays videos of say, people swimming in the pool at the club (the videos aren't live, they are videos he'll be recording and uploading for viewing on the map).

I'm lost as to how to go about all this, any help codes and tips is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For a getting started tutorial: [Adding a Map with a Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/adding-a-google-map)

You should check out https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker, it has a good explanation on how the marker portion of the api works, but also check out https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/custom-markers

Essentially you'll insert a map into your page and place custom markers on it.

Comment: I've added the map, my issue lies with the rest.

Comment: @JeremyDeey someone suggested this link for clustering markers, you should check it out - [link](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer)